Authentication problem with subversion client (1.14) during checkout
I am encountering an issue with Subversion while attempting to check out a large repository (approximately 2 GB in size). During the checkout process, the client displays an error message
svn: E120190: Error running context: An error occurred during authentication

I am confident that the credentials have been saved correctly.
I have come across a similar problem documented at https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2016-07/0076.shtml and can confirm, that setting the MaxKeepAliveRequests to 0 on the server does not resolve the issue.
My server setup consists of Ubuntu 20.04, Apache 2.4, and Subversion 1.14, with the following configuration:
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
Timeout 300
KeepAliveTimeout 5
LimitRequestBody 0
LimitXMLRequestBody 8000000
LimitRequestFieldSize 16384
SendBufferSize 0

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

A workaround for this issue would be to set the SVNAllowBulkUpdates directive to prefer. For example:
<Location "/svn/">
    ...         
    SVNAllowBulkUpdates prefer
    ...
</Location>

For more information about this issue, please refer to the following discussion on the Subversion mailing list. https://lists.apache.org/thread/xhlol7ms5h291j9qkmjty0x9hq59wmdt
